# Problema para exibir e calcular números grandes

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estou começando agora na programação com o C++, e pra testar as regras de condicional (if else...) fiz um pequeno programa para avaliar se o numero digitado pelo usuário é par ou impar. Pra isso fiz a o resto da divisão por 2 se der 0 é par senão é impar. Funciona bem pra numeros de até 8 digitos mas quando o usuario digita um número maior que isso o programa simplesmente ignora todo o resto e considera só os 8 primeiros digitos. Não sei se isso é algo meio idiota porque como disse estou começando agora no C++. Poderiam me ajudar pfvr :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){ int num;
    cout<<"Digite um numero: \n";
    scanf("%d",&num);
            
    if(num%2==0){
        cout<<"O numero "<<num<<" e par.\n";
    }else{
        cout<<"O numero "<<num<<" e impar.\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int` tem um limite máximo de 16 bits. Se quiser usar algo com mais limite, o ideal é usar o tipo `long`, que contém 32 bits ou `long long` que é 64 bits. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456902/long-vs-int-c-c-whats-the-point

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 0):

O tipo inteiro(**int**, **4 bytes**) só suporta números no intervalo [*-2.147.483.648, 2.147.483.647*]. Para números maiores você pode tentar utilizar um tipo inteiro maior (**long long**, **8 bytes**) que suporta números no intervalo [*18.446.744.073.709.551.616, 18.446.744.073.709.551.615*].

Se você só for utilizar apenas números positivos você pode utilizar o tipo (**unsigned long long**, **8 bytes**) que não utiliza o bit de sinal e vai lhe permitir números até duas vezes maiores que o tipo **long long**.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).